# Java set way to give certain amount of spaces in output?

Tags: java, string, output

How do I output a string but each part of the output can have a certain amount of characters? So say the first string gets 15 characters than the next gets another 15 and the same for the one after that?

Output

```
Output1          Output2          Output3
-------------------------------------------

String1          String2          String3
```

rather than where if String1000 has more characters than String1 it won't disrupt the outputs length

```
String1000            String2            String3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `C` style printf in Java also. Here it is:

```
String x = "someString", y = "moreStringsss", z = "end";
System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", x,y,z);
```

It outputs:

```
someString     moreStringsss  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use

```
StringUtils.rightPad("String1",15)
```

from the Apache Commons Library ([JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) and concatenate the result at your convenience.